# React: Add many events to many elements

Tags: reactjs, events, jsx

I'm pretty new to web development and just signed up to stackoverflow. So,
**Hi community!!**

My today's question was:
Is there a way to define a set of many events and then add them to multiple react elements?

This would be useful to me:

```
const events = {
   onMouseOver: this.myOverHandler,
   onMouseDown: this.myDownHandler,
   onMouseUp: this.myUpHandler,
   onMouseLeave: this.myLeaveHandler
};

<div    {...events} >No mouse event escapes!!</div>
<p      {...events} >I catch them all!!</p>
<button {...events} >Mouse event trap</button>
```

Before bugging you with silly questions, I quickly typed the code above in and...
Surprise, it works!! This is the first time in 3 months, that react does what I want and not the other way round. Haha!!

So, I'm bugging you with silly insights instead :)
The complete code follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Eventful extends Component {
  myOverHandler(e) {
    console.log("over " + e.target);
  }
  myDownHandler(e) {
    console.log("down " + e.target);
  }
  myUpHandler(e) {
    console.log("up " + e.target);
  }
  myLeaveHandler(e) {
    console.log("leave " + e.target);
  }

  render() {
    let id = "very secret";
    const events = {
      onMouseOver: this.myOverHandler,
      onMouseDown: this.myDownHandler,
      onMouseUp: this.myUpHandler,
      onMouseLeave: this.myLeaveHandler
    };

    return (
      <>
        <div {...events}>No mouse event escapes!!</div>
        <p {...events}>I catch them all!!</p>
        <button {...events}>Mouse event trap</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

This does everything I needed. I'm really happy :)

Of course, I dream on, but my luck is all used up for today.

```
<div {...events(common_parameter)}>Not too high, Ikarus!</div>
```

Comment: You can reuse the handler function for each kind of element (as long as the callback type is the same), simply add an identifying value as a function param would be fine. Or build custom component which ensures the unique id inside the callback.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You wrote a question but you seemed to have answered your own question. Is there something you would like to know still?